# Google business listing showing my business as a coach purse dealer

Tags: codeigniter, google-search-console

This website was built with the latest version of Codeigniter, and in the google search results under my business name is this? The content of my website has no such information embedded in any HTML/View/etc. How is this information popping up under my business link?

[image: Google search results]

Here's my google webmaster content keywords if this helps.

[image]

Any information on how to remove this would be GREATLY appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: You sure the site hasn't been infected? Just because you don't see the text in views doesn't mean it can't be inserted by other means (js, malicious/hijacked add provider, etc).

Comment: If you look here you can see the content being pulled from my welcome page http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?tgt=http%3A%2F%2Fbwba.org&ref_sel=Google&ua_sel=ff&fs=1 I've scoured my whole site and I'm unsure of any security holes inside the code.

Comment: What happened to the answer?